# Source control server or client that supports fully manual update or merge

Tags: git, svn, tfs, merge

We're working on a big c# project that was originally under tfs source control, was later moved to git, and evenually ended in svn source control for various reasons.

Updates to this application often require changes across multiple complex c#, js and cshtml files so it happens regularly that different tasks end up changing the same pages and sections of code, but for completely different issues, so we have frequent occurrences of multiple concurrent, non-conflicting, changes to conditions and other code-flow sections of the same functions.

Our problem is that -every- source control system we've used ends up messing with our files once we update, so we'd like to find one source control system or one client that allows ACTUAL MANUAL UPDATE of all files. We spend too much time making sure updates are proper, so we'd rather update manually to make sure everything is in order.
What we mean by this is that, due to the nature of the changes, just to name the two simplest issues we've come across, some dropdown gets assigned a value that gets overwritten by another update from a different coder, later down, or that there are multiple assignments to the same hidden input box. Obviously this is not the update tools' fault, but it's exactly what happens due to the nature of our work.

The only thing that "works" is to manually check for differences (using repository check) in every file before the actual update / pull, editing the changes manually in our local versions and thus "tricking" the update tool into -not- updating on its terms, but this is time consuming.

Regarding actual conflicts, we've used tortoisesvn's ability to automatically invalidate the entire file so for these files comparison and conflict resolution is intentionally manual, and allows us to sort the issues as we prefer.

So we kindly ask: anybody knows of a source control client or server that allows actual manual update of all files during the update / pull / fetch?

What we're imagining is something like any conflict resolution tool, but applied to the very update.
Basically we don't want updates to silently change our code, but we want to see every update that'd take place to decide 'take left or take right' and to avoid the painful work of tracing why something has stopped working.

Thanks

Comment: Regardless of SCM, the solution to your problem is to work in branches. Merge branches. Resolve conflicts manually when they arise. This is a process problem, not a tool problem.

Comment: I would say the magic words are "feature branches".... and "pull requests".

Comment: "Chaos can't be automated". Your problem isn't tool, but missing order in heads and development policy. Use "branch per task" workflow (in any SCM, and, BTW, for intensive branching|merging SVN is bad, even if not "worst" choice), inspect changes in merges, rollback bad changes **and** ORGANIZE PROCESS. Manual merges is way to hell of lost time

Comment: As I've written in the original post, it's OBVIOUS it's not tool's fault, and branch per task might alleviate the issues, but these don't answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`internal:forcedump` mergetool](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/merge-tools) in Mercurial will do the requested trick, but it's wrong path anyway and road to nowhere.

Comment: Thanks. This is a start. In our opinion, it's not the workflow that needs to adapt to the tool, but the other way around. Especially since we use the typical source control workflow in all other projects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git merge --no-commit` to merge another branch without committing it so you can inspect the changes and then commit the ones you want.  I don't believe there are any Git hosting tools that allow this, so you'd need to perform every manual merge at the command line.

However, as others have mentioned, this is not a good solution to your problem.  While Git supports this, it's going to be painful and it's not the intended use of *any* version control system.  It would be better to figure out exactly what kind of problems are occurring, and think about possible solutions for them.

For example, if you find that a list of items and a count of those items are getting out of sync, then you might decide to compute the count instead of explicitly writing it in the code.

If you find that you have multiple items using the same constant value, you could keep those values in only one list sorted by value so Git will conflict if two independent updates share the same value.  The developer can then look at the entire change and determine what needs to be updated as part of resolving the conflict.

These kinds of problems do occur rarely in development, but usually they're solved using well-known techniques to help the tools fail when possible plus using automated tests to make subtle breakage noticeable.  I highly recommend this approach rather than trying to micromanage the tooling.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. We're aware of the inherent problems in our original request, but right now refactoring or redesigning are out of the question, so we're hoping in help from the software. 
It's a downward spiral? Yes, but it's better than failing deadlines because of technicalities.